# Помогите подправить регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте я написал регулярное выражение

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9.,\u0400-\u04FF\\s'?()$:;!?]{0,10000}$"
```

Такое работает в джаве, но не подходит для php. Помогите, пожалуйста, его подправить как правильно заменить \u0400-\u04FF\ и добавить символы **"** и **'**
Спасибо.

Comment: вы бы написали в своём вопросе строку, которую нужно найти.

Comment: Я при составлении регулярок часто пользуюсь сервисом [REGEX TESTER](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: не вижу ничего, что не могло бы не работать. Надо не забыть регулярке указать модификатор `u` что бы работала с юникодом и разобраться с обратными косыми, которые скорее всего надо будет удваивать или не надо, посмотрите как php реагирует на \u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `\u` работает начиная с PHP7 причем не так как в Java. В PHP7 нужно указывать код в кодировке UTF-8 (я бы вообще вставил реальные символы `Ѐ-ӿ`);
2. Одинарные кавычки можно добавлять без всякого экранирования;
3. Двойную кавычку нужно экранировать один раз `\"` (экранировать только от парсера PHP);
4. Как правильно подсказали в комментариях - обязательно использовать флаг `u` иначе регэксп не будет воспринят как юникод-строка;
5. В `preg_` функциях регэкспы обязательно должны содержать разделители (символы начала и окончания регэкспа).

В итоге получится как-то так: `"/^[a-zA-Z0-9.,Ѐ-ӿ\\s'\"?()$:;!?]{0,10000}$/u"`